# GRUB - I want my Odin to boot with text

Tags: grub, release-odin

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" should do the trick but won't work anymore

Answer (score 1):

I suspect something is weird about the GRUB that ships with elementary OS. It ignored some of the configuration I tried on it as well, albeit I'm inexperienced with GRUB in general.

What worked for me was using `boot-repair` to reinstall GRUB. I disabled Secure Boot in the GRUB options, which reinstalled GRUB, and enabled my selections in the GRUB config file.